# `printf "2+2" | bc` returns a syntax error, `echo "2+2" | bc` works, how are they handling strings differently?

Tags: bash, printf, echo, bc

`printf "2+2" | bc` gives me a syntax error, but `echo "2+2" | bc` outputs 4, I thought printf would work fine but it didn't, could someone help me understand why?

Comment: `printf '%s\n' "2+2" | bc` newline is necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ printf "2+2\n" | bc 
4
```

Looks good to me.

`bc` won't be pleased if there's EOF before the expression line ends.